# Reveal buttons under ListView items (swipe for actions)

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I want to put buttons under a `ListView` item, as described at [Android Patterns - Swipe for action](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/swipe-for-action)

I use `Slide_out_Left` and `Slide_out_rigth` animation to `slide out` `ListView`.
When animation ends, I make it  `Invisible(View.GONE)`

```
l.getChildAt(position - l.getFirstVisiblePosition()).startAnimation(animationSlideOutLeft);

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    lv.getChildAt(pos - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

How can I put two buttons under each `ListView` item?

Comment: under total list or each item of the listview,If each item of the list use custom listview

Comment: under each item of listview. I will read about custom listview , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a seperate .xml view for the buttons, then call a view switcher when an item is clicked.

Everything about view switching is down here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html

Comment: Can i change only 1 row of ListView with buttons? Other must stay unchanged.